# Obsolete member field with property accessor (Visual Studio bug)

Tags: c#, obsolete

I have a class with a member that I need to keep for legacy code and I need to mark it as obsolete so that new code doesn't use it (without getting a warning).

Let's say the class looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    [Obsolete]
    private string _old = "...";

    [Obsolete]
    public string Old
    {
        get { return _old; }
    }
}
```

I'm declaring that the member field `_old` is obsolete to make sure that new *code inside the class* do not use that field.

I'm also declaring that the property `Old` is obsolete to make sure that *code outside of the class* do not use the property.

When I compile this I get a warning in the property getter saying that `_old` is obsolete. I thought that the compiler would silently ignore this since the property itself is obsolete.

Am I missing something or do I need to add `#pragma warning disable/restore` for obsolete member fields everywhere they're used (even though the method/property itself is marked as obsolete)?

---

The reason that "*I thought that the compiler would silently ignore this*" is because it seems to do so for obsolete classes:

```
[Obsolete]
public class MyObsoleteClass
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        // No warning here, since the class itself is obsolete
        return new MyClass().Old;
    }
}
```

---

As @Heinzi answered: this seems to be due to a bug in Visual Studio. I've filed a report on connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1146809

---

It turns out that the bug in Visual Studio is not just limited to accessing an obsolete field from a property.

Accessing an obsolete property from an obsolete method should not yield a warning:

```
public class Class2
{
    [Obsolete]
    public string Property { get; set; }

    [Obsolete]
    public void Method()
    {
        this.Property = "value"; // <-- Incorrect warning reported
    }
}
```

Neither should doing so from another class:

```
public class Class3
{
    [Obsolete]
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class Class4
{
    [Obsolete]
    public string Method()
    {
        return new Class3().Property; // <-- Incorrect warning reported
    }
}
```

Interestingly, it works in the following class and when adding this class the other warnings (from `Class4` and `Class2`) will magically disappear.

```
public class Class5
{
    [Obsolete]
    public void Method()
    {
        // No warning reported here, which is good.
        // This magically makes the other warnings disappear too!
        new Class2().Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not refactor the (internal) code to use the right internal field? Then you have the warning just once (for the property) which is the Obsolete-attribute is designed for - external use.

Comment: I need to keep the field as it is. Legacy code need to keep using it. However, that code will be marked obsolete as well. New code shall use the new stuff, but old code shall be able to still exist and use the old stuff.

Comment: "*I thought that the compiler would silently ignore this since the property itself is obsolete.*" What made you think so? Is there something in the documentation that indicates this?

Comment: Are you sure the warning is still there after you recompile the project? On my PC (VS 2012), the warning disappears after recompiling. .NET Fiddle seems to agree: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVFN5a (try removing [Obsolete] from the property and you will get the warning, add it, and the warning disappears).

Comment: @Heinzi: It sometimes disappear but as soon as I make changes to the code the warning appear again. Perhaps it is just the "background compiler" that generate this warning. If so, it's very annoying...

Comment: @MårtenWikström: Then it seems to be a bug in Visual Studio. Recompile the project and check the "Output" tab: The warning should be there when [Obsolete] is removed, and it should be gone when [Obsolete] is re-added. Everything else is Visual Studio magic rather than the compiler's fault.

Comment: What you describe is true in Xamarin Studio 5.7.1 and mono 3.12.0; there are no obsolete warnings when compiling your code. Removing the [Obsolete] attribute on your method will generate a warning about accessing the obsolete field. This is also how I remembered Visual Studio to work, but I am unable to find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, and your understanding of how the `Obsolete` attribute should work is correct: If you look at the "Output" tab after compilation, you will note that *the compiler* does not output a warning for your case (but *will* output a warning if you remove the `Obsolete` attribute from your property, as expected).

You are right, though, that Visual Studio sometimes displays a warning after making arbitrary changes to the code. This seems to be a bug in Visual Studio. If you can still reproduce it with the most current version, I would suggest that you file a bug report on http://connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4. Not sure whether that is considered the most current version though.

Comment: I've checked with the command line compiler `csc`. Not getting any warnings there. So it seems to be a bug in Visual Studio like you said.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a clever feature, but I don't see any indication in the documentation that it *should* work this way. On the other hand I would not use the `Obsolate` attribute on a private member (if the class is not extremly huge), but I would refactor it instead. I your case I would write this:

```
class MyClass
{
    [Obsolete]
    public string Old
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

And then you only need to change the usages of `_old` to `Old` and the problem is solved.

Comment: I need to keep the private member. Both for legacy code within the class and for serialization contract.

Comment: Well for the legacy code this wouldn't be a too dangerous change. (If you are not explicitly forbidden to make changes to it.) I am not familiar with the serialization contract, so I sadly can't comment on that ...